# If ol list is styled decimal attribute disappears

Tags: html

I have a ordered list inside a styled div. After styling the enummeratin disappears. What can I do?

HTML

```
<div class="box">
  <ol>


    <li>.....</li>
            <li>.....</li>

  </ol>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .box ol{
list-style-type: decimal;
}

.box ol li{
display: block;

margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because of the `display: block;`. If you want to have the bullets (or numbers), don't set `display: block`, or do set `display: list-item`.

Answer (score 0):

While you've accepted an answer, it's worth noting that, If you need the list items to be `display: block`, then you can (in compliant browsers) also use CSS generated content to restore the list-markers:

```
.box ol {
    counter-reset: listNumber;
}

.box ol li::before {
    counter-increment: listNumber;
    content: counter(listNumber, decimal);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4eyFb/1/).

But this approach, while it works, is needlessly complex and has the usual cross-browser issues.